# Windows Azure Website Communicate with Android Device

Tags: android, azure

Requirement of project: **communication between windows azure Website and android device using azure mobile services**

1)Website is build in VB.NET using Microsoft Windows Azure (server side)

2)Android Application is on Android Device (client side)

The client (Android user) should be able to send data from android device (client side) to Website (Server side) and vice-versa To make this possible i.e. Communcation Between client and sever I am using Mobile Services provided by Microsoft Windows Azure (server side) which use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)

I have Followed all steps according to the documentation

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-push-android/

Also followed all steps as been provided in the above link documentation of Microsoft windows azure

but when I try to send message from Android device towards the website the following error occurs

*Error:* **com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: Error while processing request**

Note: GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) gives us an gcm.jar file which is used in the android app to send data towards Server i.e website

ONCREATE CODE

```
           @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);


    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
    mRegistationId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    if (mRegistationId.equals("")) {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    }

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingProgressBar);

    // Initialize the progress bar
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

    try {
        // Create the Mobile Service Client instance, using the provided
        // Mobile Service URL and key
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                "url of website",
                "POBHgxwAktyxUdeRRpcFyqEcsppwiS99",
                this).withFilter(new ProgressFilter());

        // Get the Mobile Service Table instance to use
        mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(ToDoItem.class);

        mTextNewToDo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textNewToDo);

        // Create an adapter to bind the items with the view
        mAdapter = new ToDoItemAdapter(this, R.layout.row_list_to_do);
        ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewToDo);
        listViewToDo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Load the items from the Mobile Service
        refreshItemsFromTable();
                    }
                    catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    createAndShowDialog(new Exception("There was an error creating the Mobile Service. Verify the URL"), "Error");
                }
                }
```

On BUTTON click event addItem() is called

```
            public void addItem(View view) {
    if (mClient == null) {
        return;
    }

    try
    {

    // Create a new item
    ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem();

    item.setText(mTextNewToDo.getText().toString());
    item.setComplete(false);

    // Insert the new item
    mToDoTable.insert(item, new TableOperationCallback<ToDoItem>() {

        public void onCompleted(ToDoItem entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {

            if (exception == null) {
                if (!entity.isComplete()) {
                    mAdapter.add(entity);
                }
            } else {
                createAndShowDialog(exception, "Error");
            }

        }
    });

    item.setRegistrationId(mRegistationId.equals("") ?
            GCMIntentService.getRegistrationId() : mRegistationId);
    mTextNewToDo.setText("");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

            public void checkItem(ToDoItem item) {
    if (mClient == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Set the item as completed and update it in the table
    item.setComplete(true);

    mToDoTable.update(item, new TableOperationCallback<ToDoItem>() {

        public void onCompleted(ToDoItem entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if (exception == null) {
                if (entity.isComplete()) {
                    mAdapter.remove(entity);
                }
            } else {
                createAndShowDialog(exception, "Error");
            }
        }

    });
}

            private void refreshItemsFromTable() {

    // Get the items that weren't marked as completed and add them in the
    // adapter
    mToDoTable.where().field("complete").eq(val(false)).execute(new TableQueryCallback<ToDoItem>() {

        public void onCompleted(List<ToDoItem> result, int count, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if (exception == null) {
                mAdapter.clear();

                for (ToDoItem item : result) {
                    mAdapter.add(item);
                }

            } else {
                createAndShowDialog(exception, "Error");
            }
        }
    });
}


private void createAndShowDialog(Exception exception, String title) {
    createAndShowDialog(exception.toString(), title);
}



private void createAndShowDialog(String message, String title) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.create().show();
}



             private class ProgressFilter implements ServiceFilter {

    @Override
    public void handleRequest(ServiceFilterRequest request, NextServiceFilterCallback nextServiceFilterCallback,
            final ServiceFilterResponseCallback responseCallback) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mProgressBar != null) mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        nextServiceFilterCallback.onNext(request, new ServiceFilterResponseCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(ServiceFilterResponse response, Exception exception) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mProgressBar != null) mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    }
                });

                if (responseCallback != null)  responseCallback.onResponse(response, exception);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, nor a detailed error message, it's going to be very hard to help you solve your problem. Consider posting some of the pertinent client code and server code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the tutorial is using ' instead of ", which in my case was the problem. The issue was in the Insert script on azure. Hope it helps you :-)